# Formatting current system date in Common Lisp

Tags: date, formatting, common-lisp

I am trying to get the current system date in Common Lisp through following function

```
(defun current-date-string ()
  "Returns current date as a string."
  (multiple-value-bind (sec min hr day mon yr dow dst-p tz)
                       (get-decoded-time)
    (declare (ignore sec min hr dow dst-p tz))
    (format nil "~A-~A-~A" yr mon day)))
```

Unfortunately I am getting the current date in this format "2014-1-2". However actually I need this format "2014-01-02". Is any way we can change the format? I tried replacing nil with  yyyy-mm-dd but no luck. However my machine clock shows the date format is "2014-01-02".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[What you need is](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cbb.htm)

```
(format nil "~4,'0d-~2,'0d-~2,'0d" yr mon day)
```

`~2,'0d` means:

- `d`: decimal output (instead of your generic `a`)
- `2`: 1st argument: width
- `'0`: 2nd argument: pad char `0`

I suggest that you read up on [Formatted Output](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm); `format` is a very powerful tool.

Comment: Ah I understand. It will run in SBCL if I use unused variables for `_`, but then of course it gives warnings and it is indeed, in my opinion, "untidy". I'll remove it since I agree that I would therefore prefer the more idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

[simple-date-time is what you need, it contains some convenient function to format date and time.](https://github.com/quek/simple-date-time)